# I am getting an Error with Regexp getting a expression

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to extract a group text from a html matching some regular expression with Regexp code but it give me an error I don´t know how to resolve.

This is the html source http://www.morningstar.es/es/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000T4PD&tab=1

And this is the code I use:

```
var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();


 output=html.match(new RegExp("Año</td><td class="col2 value number">(.*)</td><td class="col3 value number/">", 'i'))[1]);
```

I try to get the data in red circle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bgbn.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var url = "http://www.morningstar.es/es/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000T4PD&tab=1"; // Added
var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
output = html.match(/Año<\/td><td class="col2 value number">(.*)<\/td>/i)[1]; // Modified
Logger.log(output) // 0,77
```

- If you want to use `new RegExp()`, please use the following script:

  ```
  output = html.match(new RegExp('Año</td><td class="col2 value number">(.*)</td>', 'i'))[1];
  ```

#### Reference:

- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

### Edit:

For example, when `new RegExp()` is used, the regex can be created using the variable like the following sample script.

```
var value = 'def';
var r = new RegExp('abc' + value);
Logger.log(r) // /abcdef/
```

Comment: @Moselan Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, the script works. But if your environment cannot access to the URL, the value cannot be retrieved. When you checked the value of ``html``, can you find the value you want?

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much.Sorry I was wrong, it runs perfectly. What´s the difference between using RegExp o not?

Comment: @Moselan Thank you for your response.